# XAMARIN, API, and Remote MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, .net, database, api, xamarin

I have a MySQL Database that is hosted on Host Gator. I have a desktop application that that I created that connects to the MySQL Database where I can add and retrieve data from the database. I want to develop a simple app using XAMARIN that can connect to the MySQL Database that is hosted on Host Gator. I want to be able to add data to the database and receive data from the database. I have been told that connecting straight to the database form XAMARIN is bad practice and it is recommended to create an API. How can I create an API that connects to the MySQL Database that is hosted on Host Gator? Is it possible? The app would just be used by friends and family and would not be available on any app stores.

Host Gator Control Panel:
[Host Gator Control Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlnZ6.png)

[Host Gator Control Panel Continued](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFcej.png)

Comment: Short answer, yes. Long answer too long to fit into StackOverflow QA. But Host Gator has VPS and Dedicated Servers, you can run anything there.

Comment: What path should I start researching. I'm so lost on what my next step should be.

Comment: If you want to create a small API around your database, look up some tutorials on ASP.NET Core or similar web frameworks. As for installing, and running on Host Gator, I don't know. Not familiar with their hosting services. But should™️ just be a matter of creating an executable of your project and running it there.

Comment: Okay lets say I start developing an WebAPI with ASP.NET. How do I then get it to connect to the host gator MySQL Database? Thank you for your help by the way!
Would this course give me the knowledge to create the API and connect it to the MySQL Database? [Udemy Course](https://www.udemy.com/course/learning-aspnet-web-api/)

Comment: I have added 2 pictures showing Host Gator's control panel. There is one portion Link that says Site Software. So after I created the API using ASP.NET, I could in theory somehow add the program to Host Gator which would allow me to connect to the API from a mobile app that then connects to the MySQL Database on Host Gator?

Comment: I think I have found a tutorial that will set me on the right track, Before purchasing do you can review this course to see if it will suffice? [RESTful API with ASP.NET Core Web API - Create and Consume](https://www.udemy.com/course/quick-introduction-to-aspnet-mvc-core-20/)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The Host Gator shared hosting doesn't look like it supports ASP.NET Core, so you might need to bump to a dedicated server or VPS. Alternatively find a different host. All the big cloud providers have ways to run ASP.NET Core. You could also learn PHP or whatever language Host Gator supports and write your API using that.

Comment: Cheesebaron, you have provided me with enough information to get working on my problem. Can you post your latest comment as an answer so I can mark this as answered? I will get in contact with Host Gator to see what can be done in terms of upgrading to support ASP.NET or what methods I can use to get an API coded in PHP running on their hosting service. If I am unable to obtain that information from Host Gator, what would a cheap alternative be where I could host a MySQL Database and Run the ASP.NET app on the cloud? Cheap meaning around $20/ mo.